# Batch file FOR /f tokens

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, token

Can anyone please explain exactly how the following code works, line by line. I'm really lost. I've been trying to learn how to use the FOR command but I don't understand this.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in (myfile) do (
  set line=%%f
  call :processToken
  )
  goto :eof

:processToken

  for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %%a in ("%line%") do (
  echo Got one token: %%a
  set line=%%b
  )
  if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
  goto :eof
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in (myfile) do
```

This reads a file line-by-line, removing leading spaces (thanks, jeb).

```
set line=%%f
```

sets then the `line` variable to the line just read and

```
call :procesToken
```

calls a subroutine that does something with the line

```
:processToken
```

is the start of the subroutine mentioned above.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %%a in ("%line%") do
```

will then split the line at `/`, but stopping tokenization after the first token.

```
echo Got one token: %%a
```

will output that first token and

```
set line=%%b
```

will set the `line` variable to the rest of the line.

```
if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
```

And if `line` isn't yet empty (i.e. all tokens processed), it returns to the start, continuing with the rest of the line.

Comment: +1, But the first `FOR /F "tokens=* delims= "` removes all leading spaces from the line

Comment: The %%b is pure misinformation. Only %%a is assigned in the loop and line=%%b would just assign "%b" to "line"