# Processing an input file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file to read an input text file, extract information from it put it in an output file.

1. Each line in the input file has different information so I want the batch to loop through each line.
2. I want to extract certain information from the input file and discard the rest.
3. The input file can have any number of lines.
4. I want to leave an error message if the input line has no useful information.
5. I need two counters, the first telling the number of lines in the input file, and the second telling the number of lines in the output file (without counting empty lines) .
6. I want the batch to treat special characters like normal letters.

For example:

```
FILE_NAME=apple FILE_SIZE=312     C=fwef sdf asdetg

FILE_SIZE=7867 C=ehtrghr  FILE_NAME=sea&ocean G=tryr    yujg
C=gert FILE_NAME=chair=12 tgrgd sfsf FILE_SIZE=66
dfgg ertergf C=ert A=344

fgdfg FILE_NAME=cat
```

I want to extract only the `FILE_NAME=XXX` and `FILE_SIZE=XXX` part, discarding everything else in that line. The output should be:

```
-name apple -size 312
-name sea&ocean -size 7867
-name chair=12 -size 66
ERROR!!!
-name cat

 input_count=5 and output_count=4
```

Comment: I know this isn't batch file method so probably not suitable, but awk and sed are both (linux) command line tools for re-arranging lines of text such as this one.

Comment: Maybe you could download the `sed` and `awk` versions from UnxUtils project and use them in your batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People don't give enough credit to batch scripts. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT_FILE=input.txt
set OUTPUT_FILE=output.txt
set INPUT_COUNT=0
set OUTPUT_COUNT=0

:: Read the input file
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (%INPUT_FILE%) do call :ParseLine "%%s"
echo. >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
echo input_count=!INPUT_COUNT! and output_count=!OUTPUT_COUNT! >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
exit /b

:: Parse one line and write to output
:ParseLine
set "str=%~1"
set ^"str=!str: =^

!"
set file_name=
set file_size=
for /f "eol=  tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("!str!") do (
    set "tag=%%a"
    set "value=%%b"
    if "!tag!" equ "FILE_NAME" set "file_name=-name !value!"
    if "!tag!" equ "FILE_SIZE" set "file_size=-size !value!"
)
set /a input_count+=1
if "!file_name!" equ "" if "!file_size!" equ "" (
    echo ERROR^^!^^!^^! >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
    goto Done
)
echo.!file_name! !file_size! >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
set /a output_count+=1
:Done
```

Here's a little explanation about what this does:

1. The first `for` loop reads the file line by line, the contents of each line being sent as input arguments to the `ParseLine` subroutine.
2. The `ParseLine` subroutine receives each line in `str` and iterates through its space-separated words (using jeb's advanced method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494490/1336150)).
   The logic of the subroutine loop is pretty straightforward: it breaks each word into `tag` (the text that precedes `=`) and `value` (the text that follows `=`), and sets `file_name` and `file_size` accordingly.

I believe that this method can handle pretty much any input file, with or without special characters.

Comment: ok but that will change for all variables FILE_NAME & FILE_SIZE but I want to do for 1 of them

Comment: @user1447199 - You shouldn't change your question completely, better ask a new one. It's a big difference, if it's XML, CSV or custom format

Comment: help plz , I noticed that there is a problem if the input file name has spaces in this line for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (%INPUT_FILE%) do call :ParseLine "%%s" , I tried to put "%INPUT_FILE%" but it didn't work , is there a solution ?

Comment: I found a valid solution , i made a swap like this , set input2="%INPUT_FILE%" and then : for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (%input2%) do call :ParseLine "%%s" and it worked , but maybe there is a smarter solution

Comment: I have a question , is it possible to use a word instead of `=` as a delimiter

Comment: @Leo92, no it's not possible, you'll have to use another trick to achieve that.