# Batch file - for loop only prints out the first item

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here is my batch file, try.cmd:

```
for /f "delims=;" %%d in ("%PATH%") do echo %%d
```

Curiously, only the first directory in the path got printed, then the loop stopped. How do I get to loop over all directories in the path?

Comment: It only prints the first token.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493493/how-to-loop-through-tokens-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO %path:;=&ECHO(%
```

?

Your version doesn't work because `for /f` is required to invoke the `delims=` facility, but that means that there's only one input "line"; the `for` command will iterate through a sequence, but that means there's no `delims` available...

Answer (score 2):

```
@SETLOCAL
@ECHO OFF
SET "P=%PATH%"
:EXTRACT_LOOP
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%p in ("%P%") do (echo %%p & SET P=%%q)
IF NOT "%P%" == "" GOTO :EXTRACT_LOOP
```

There might be another smart way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### Printf.bat

```
@echo off
:loop
Echo %~1
shift /1
if "%~1" NEQ "" goto loop
```

#### Cmd

```
C:\>Printf.bat 1 2 3 4 5 6
1
2
3
4
5
6

C:\>set test=A;B;C;D
C:\>Printf.bat %test:;= %
A
B
C
D

C:\>Printf.bat %Path:;= %
...

C:\>
```