# Save multiple tokens from a command output using "for /f"

Tags: android, windows, batch-file

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495889/7748586) answer is what I want to do, but it works for strings **NOT** command output.

My script is:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,3,5,7" %%a in ('adb devices') do (
echo %%a

set dev1=%%a
set dev2=%%b
set dev3=%%c
set dev4=%%d
)
echo.
echo Devices are: !dev1!, !dev2!, !dev3!, !dev4!
pause
```

But it shows 1 device, instead of the 2 available:

```
770a56
emulator-5554

Devices are: emulator-5554, , ,
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Sample output from Windows:

```
C:\Windows\Right\Console2>adb devices
List of devices attached
BH90W3T416      device
HSMPG9265D606183        device
emulator-5554   device
```

Comment: Can you show sample output of `adb devices`?

Comment: LotPings added one, Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store *several values*, each one in its *own variable* when such a number is not known in advance (why do you use 4 variables if there are 2 devices?), you need to use an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set n=0
for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('adb devices') do (
   echo %%a

   set /A n+=1
   set dev!n!=%%a
)
echo/
echo Devices are: 
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !dev%%i!
pause
```

Comment: Know any book (not site) that help in doing batch files?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
set dev1=!dev1!,%%a
set dev2=!dev2!,%%b
set dev3=!dev3!,%%c
set dev4=!dev4!,%%d
...
echo Devices are: !dev1:~1!, !dev2:~1!, !dev3:~1!, !dev4:~1!
```

which will establish a list for each `dev` with a leading comma.

Since you don't show us raw input and don't explain why you are specifying 4 tokens but showing only one, your question is unclear. If `%%a` is the only token of interest, then

```
...
set "dev4=!dev3!"
set "dev3=!dev2!"
set "dev2=!dev1!"
set "dev1=%%a"
...
```

may be more suitable.

Comment: I edited the **raw** command output in the question to clarify.
Taking a tip from your 1st code, I can just do:

    `set devices=!devices!,%%a`
Then split the devices string by commas and parse them like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495889/7748586), thanks it works.

Strangely the 2nd part of your code truncates the 1st letter of each device, but that's not a problem now.